# Any way to access the value from xml

Tags: xslt-2.0

I'm trying to access values from my xml file using "title" xpath without using /Para000_* because _1,_2 is dynamic.

Is there any way to access the value without using para number please help me 
I need value only "Mango" but i'm getting "Mango Orange" values

I have an xml as follows:

```
 <Content code="" title="Food" type="Fruits" paraCode="2">
  <props>
    <para001_2 title="F1">Mango</para001_2>
    <para002_2 title="F2">Grape</para002_2>
 </props>
 </Content>
 <Content code="" title="Food" type="Fruits" paraCode="2">
 <props>
   <para001_2 title="F1">Orange</para001_2>
   <para002_2 title="F2">Grape</para002_2>
 </props>
 </Content>

tried XSLT as follows:
<xsl:variable name="FruitName" select="/Content/props/*[@title = 'F1']"/>
```

Result:
    Mango

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<xsl:variable name="FruitName" select="/Content/props/*[@title = 'F1'][not(preceding::Content/props/*[@title = 'F1'])]"/>
```

Comment: Hi please see above i'm facing that problem..... i'm getting all the values with title F1

Comment: Thanks for the help i'm getting only first value always.... how can i get second value.... i.e, Orange
because i need to loo through all the values once

Comment: you can use `for-each select="Content/props/*[@title = 'F1']"` to loop all values

Answer (score 0):

Please mention on what basis/condition you want access the node `<Content>`

For the current input given, to access the first node's `title`

The solution can be:

```
<xsl:value-of select="root/Content/props/*[1][@title = 'F1']"/>
```